# How do I change an old 3 round pin socket to a square pin socket in a newer house?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I live in a relatively newly built house (15-20 years old), yet the last owner fitted old 3 round pin sockets in the lounge, possible for old fashioned table lamps.

Can I safely replace the round pin sockets with new square ones, just to use for one lamp (i.e. not overload with adapters and multiple devices)?

The plug on the lamp will of course contain a 13 amp fuse.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the sockets in question are on the lighting circuit.

Nothing explicitly forbids putting 13A sockets on a lighting circuit. However it is widely seen as bad practice because future users of the installation may plug larger loads into the socket and trip out the lights.

Better to change the plug on the lamp or to buy or make an adapter.

Answer (score 0):

There were/are two sizes of BS547 round-pin sockets. small 5A sockets for lighting, larger 15A sockets for appliances.

It would be wrong to replace a small 5A BS547 socket with a 13A BS1363 socket. The wiring would not be safe for 13A and simply changing the fuse/MCB at the consumer-unit(fusebox) to a higher rating would be dangerous.

In the UK I expect this change would count as Part-P notifiable and you'd need to get a registered electrician to either do the work (including any necessary rewiring and changes at the consumer-unit) or to inspect and certify the result.

Comment: unless the previous owner used overrated wiring for those sockets